# Sonatype Nexus: Hide Uploader's IP Address

Tags: maven, nexus, dependency-management, nexus3

I'm using a hosted sonatype nexus for dependency distribution but I want to hide the IP address of my computer from being easily accessible from browsing the repository. How can I disable this being shown? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyqxt.png

Apologies if this belongs on superuser, there's no tags over there for sonatype or nexus so I came here instead.

NXRM version 3.16.1-02